# Why do Android activities stay in memory when navigating to another?

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, release

I am developing a simple android application. Whilst navigating through the activities the memory usage just increases when starting those Activities, even when I get back to the previous activities.

I used `finish();` and `finishAffinity();` methods, and tried clearing static variables when I start those Activities but the problem persists. Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

You should read the basic activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Editing : 
On the link : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

> Note: Because the system retains your Activity instance in system memory when it is stopped ...

That's how the android OS is designed. It does not kill and recreate. Thus it gives you better performance. 
However, it might kill and recreate when system is running out of memory.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Also, please avoid link only answers (refer to the help section). Finally, could you explain what specific part of the given link can answer the OP's question and why?